# Enabling Tiger Geocoder in postgis version 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew, postgis, rails-postgresql

I have used homebrew to update to the most recent version of postgis. (2.1)

```
brew unlink postgis
brew install postgis
```

I then have created a migration to alter the postgis extension to 2.1

```
rails g migration alter_postgis_version

def change
  execute %q{ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.1.0";}
end
```

## Edit:

Ran the brew commands in the first comment and now am getting the following error when I migrate:

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist:
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0- 
p247@freight_alert/gems/activerecord4.0.0/
lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'
```

I have postgis set up under a schema of postgis, so if I run

```
$: set search_path = "$user", postgis,public;
$: \d
                             List of relations
 Schema  |           Name           |   Type   |       Owner       
---------+--------------------------+----------+-------------------
 postgis | geography_columns        | view     | me
 postgis | geometry_columns         | view     | me
 etc..

$: \d geometry_columns

                View "postgis.geometry_columns"
      Column       |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------------+------------------------+-----------
 f_table_catalog   | character varying(256) | 
 f_table_schema    | character varying(256) | 
 f_table_name      | character varying(256) | 
 f_geometry_column | character varying(256) | 
 coord_dimension   | integer                | 
 srid              | integer                | 
 type              | character varying(30)  |
```

However if I try to run:

```
$: CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

This doesn't make any sense to me since geometry_columns is in the list of relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this. Went away after I reinstalled geos, gdal, and libspatialite (relinking each as well). I can't say this is the recipe to copy/paste, but play with it and see if you can get it to work:

```
brew reinstall gdal
brew unlink gdal && brew link gdal
brew reinstall geos
brew unlink geos && brew link geos
brew reinstall libspatialite
brew unlink libspatialite && brew link libspatialite
```

You might have to do it in a different order, or redo one after the other in a way that gets the libraries in order. Don't uninstall postgis-2.0.x either, since you'll need the (both) libraries to soft-upgrade.

Comment: Hmm that seems to have done most of the work but now my script is failing on creating the postgis tiger geocoder. I have edited the error message above.

Comment: I solved your original problem, please award appropriate points.

Comment: I wanted to split the bounty between you two, but SO doesn't allow that. I wanted to start another bounty but SO only allows you increase bounty, since mine was 250 it would be 500. You get an upvote and acceptance. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure postgis schema is in your database search_path. Afterward, reconnect to your database and try again. Should look something like this.

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path = public, postgis;
```

There is a small bug we introduced in postgis_tiger_geocoder so might want to use he 2.1.1 one or manually patch the loader described here:

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/317-CREATE-SCHEMA-IF-NOT-EXISTS-in-9.3-and-tiger-geocoder.html